# GAE: Messenger monthly pricing

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to estimate the pricing for a messenger iOS/Android app running under Google App Engine. However, the pricing info [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine) doesn't really give me any usable information.

I plan on building the messenger via the XMPP API, but I will also share photos, conduct searches etc. I'd be able to calculate/guess the amount of messages, their sizes and the sizes of the photos, however I don't really understand the concept of Frontend Instance hours and how to estimate them.

## Data to calculate with

- 100 000 users (profile with images - together cca 3 MB)
- 80 messages per user per day
- 2 photos per user per day (photo size: 200 KB)

## Services (APIs)

- Datastore API/High replication data storage (for sending pictures, user profiles)
- Search API (searching for users)
- Blobstore API (to store images in the user's profile)
- XMPP API (messenger)

Now here is where it gets tricky for me... Does the XMPP per stanza price also add to the Instance Hours and Out/In network traffic? And what about the other APIs?

If I can approximate the number of requests, can I calculate the number of needed Instance hours?

The most important thing to realise - **do I need to calculate the HOSTING (in/out traffic, instance hours, datastore) and API (XMPP, Search, Datastore) prices separately or are they inclusive?** Meaning that for example for every message I will be charged twice, the XMPP stanza price and the in/out traffic price, or does the XMPP stanza price already contain all other costs (traffic+instance hours)?

As far as I researched, this isn't really explained in any of the documents. Most of the others trying to estimate the price just ended up with the trial & failure method - launching their system and observing the approximate monthly price... However that is not good enough for me :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about estimating a monthly cost of service, not programming.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, okay, however this calculation determines the way the app will be programmed and weather it is wise to go with GAE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Out/In network traffic**

XMPP:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/#Python_Quotas_and_limits

Network quota:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests

When the application will execute your code, then it will consume Instance Hours. Number of Instance Hours will depend on how complex the code. Max HTTP request is 60sec for Frontend Instance.

So, HOSTING and API prices are separately.

Tip 1: Start by calculating the cost of a single event (photo, message, etc).

Tip 2: From my experience the most difficult is estimate Datastore reads/writes and storage (in our app huge part of storage are indexes).

Comment: So is there a way to estimate the number requests + the requests of the XMPP API in terms of instance hours? So I know how many Reserved Frontend Instances I'd need...

Comment: From what I understood - each operation needs some time to complete, a few ms... If it would take 200ms, 1 second could complete 5. To rephrase - how long will the XMPP operations take to complete?

Comment: @MartinHerman approximate calculations: If your app need 1sec for processing XMPP request then approximately in 1min you can process 60 request per 1 frontend instance.

Comment: @MartinHerman conitinuation and minimal 60 XMPP API Calls + min. 30 XMPP Stanzas Sent + 30 XMPP Invitations + 60 x 1k(1k per message) XMPP Data Sent etc.

Comment: @MartinHerman XMPP takes no time of Frontend Instace but you need a piece of code (python, java, php, go) to process incoming/sent message.

Comment: okay great, I'm done with the calculation :)

Comment: Two last tips: 1.Database read/write ops are most difficult to predict and 2. x1,5 or x2 all your calculations :)

Comment: thats what I actually did :)